# WebAPI: Make operation method enabled/visible only for minimum/maxium API version

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a simple WebAPI controller, looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiVersion("3.0")]
[RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger) {_logger = logger;}


    /// <summary>
    /// defined version neutral
    /// </summary>
    [ApiVersionNeutral]
    [HttpGet("health")]
    public string Health()
    {
        return "I'm Version independent";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// defined in version 1 - yet valid for all API versions
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet("ring")]
    public string Ring()
    {
        return "All API Versions";
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// defined in version 1
    /// </summary>
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpGet("ping")]
    public string Ping()
    {
        return "API Version (1)";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// defined in version 2
    /// </summary>
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    [MapToApiVersion("3.0")]
    [HttpGet("ping")]
    public string Ping2()
    {
        return "API Version (2) [a changed version from V1]";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// defined in vresion 3
    /// </summary>
    [MapToApiVersion("3.0")]
    [HttpGet("pong")]
    public string Pong()
    {
        return "API Version 3";
    }
}
```

When I add a new version because either a new operation arrived or an operation has changed, I have now to add the `MapToApiVersion` attribute for every method, which already has at least one such attribute and should exist in further version as well and also for all methods which should not anymore exposed in the new version.

For example for a new version 4, I would like to archive the *ring* operation, means I have to change it as follow (compare with complete class code above):

```
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    [MapToApiVersion("3.0")]
    [HttpGet("ring")]
    public string Ring()
    {
        return "All API Versions";
    }
```

And the *ping* operation, exposed through `ping2` method, which should further exist in new version (compare with complete class code above) to be changed like this:

```
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    [MapToApiVersion("3.0")]
    [MapToApiVersion("4.0")]
    [HttpGet("ping")]
    public string Ping2()
    {
        return "API Version (2) [a changed version from V1]";
    }
```

So I'm wondering, if there is a simpler way to declare a controller method (not the operation, this could still exists through another method ...) to be active from a certain API version or up to a certain API version. Simply spoken I search something like `MapToApiVersionMin("4.0")` and `MapToApiVersionMax("3.0")`.

And besides, I haven't found out, what the difference is between `ApiVersion` and `MapToApiVersion` attribute on method level. For me it seems to do the same job ...

I'm working against .NET 6
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: The [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97ff0a19-8a0d-45fc-9a70-a333b88c50a3/few-questions-about-web-api-versioning-in-core?forum=aspwebapi) tells the difference berween `MapToApiVersion` and `ApiVersion`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I knew that one, the answer there is very sloppy, or as my complier would say "Not sufficient entropy" :)